# Node-horseman with promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, phantomjs, bluebird

I'm trying to use promises inside horseman's *evalute* function. A simple example:

```
var Horseman = require('node-horseman');
var horseman = new Horseman();

horseman
  .open('http://google.com')
  .evaluate(function() {
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
      setTimeout(function(){resolve("Hello")},2000);  
    });
    return promise;
  })
  .then(function(mesg){
    console.log(mesg);
  })
  .close();
```

I'm expecting the resolved value "Hello" to be passed to the next *then* function as the *mesg* argument when the promise is fulfilled, but instead I'm getting the following error:

```
Unhandled rejection fn
evaluate

global code
evaluateJavaScript@[native code]
evaluate@phantomjs://platform/webpage.js:390:39
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PhantomJS has a very limited communications channel into and out of the browser. It has to send everything over basically a text-based path so it has to serialize what it sends in, and deserialize what comes out.

You can send "in" a function to be executed inside the browser's JS context because it's just converting it to a string. But what comes out can't be a promise because you lose the whole object wrapped around it. You can only return scalar values and primitive objects. If you look at the example provided in the module's [home page](https://github.com/johntitus/node-horseman), a primitive object is returned:

```
.evaluate( function(selector){
  // Trimmed for clarity...
  return {
    height : $( selector ).height(),
    width : $( selector ).width()
  }
}, '.thumbimage')
```

Node-horseman does have a pattern for async operations, but instead of returning a promise you must call a `done()` function that you ask to be given as a param to your function:

```
.evaluate(function(ms, done){
    var start = Date.now();
    setTimeout(function() {
        done(null, Date.now() - start);
    }, ms);
}, 100)
```

The return value from `evaluate()` is already a promise. You don't need to return one of your own. You just need to do any async work you want, and then call `done()` with your result value.